# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.ANGULAR-CHARTJS

Tags: angular, charts

THIS IS app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GraficaService } from './services/grafica.service'
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'yoga';
  chart = [];

  constructor( private _grafica: GraficaService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this._grafica.graficoEstadistico()
     .subscribe(res => {

        let temp_max = res['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_max)
        let temp_min = res['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_min)
        let alldates = res['list'].map(res => res.dt)

        let weatherDates = []

        alldates.forEach((res) => {
          let jsdate = new Date(res * 1000)
          weatherDates.push(jsdate.toLocaleTimeString('en'), {year: 'numeric', month:'short',day:'numeric'})         
        });

        console.log(weatherDates);

        this.chart = new Chart('canvas',{
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: weatherDates,
            datasets: [
              {
                data: temp_max,
                borderColor: '#3cba9f',
                fill:false

              },
              {
                data: temp_min,
                borderColor: '#ffcc00',
                fill:false

              },
            ]
          },

          options: {
            legend:{
              display:false
            },
            scales:{
              xAxes:[{
                display: true
              }],
              yAxes:[{
                display: true
              }]
            }
          }
        })


     })


    // Yo puedo presentar mi json por consola ,asi . De manera continuada al this
    //.subscribe(res => console.log(res))

  }
}
```

I'm currently using in an ANGULAR project the "chartjs" library, to generate statistical graphs, but when running the project in console I get the following error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined,
What can be a solution?

core.js:15714 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at SafeSubscriber._next (app.component.ts:22)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:38)

Comment: please, show us your code

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading these articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The only place that you used `map` function is after `res['list']` means, when you get `res` there is no `list` property on it.

To investigate do `console.log(res)` at the beginning of `subscribe` and watch what is there.

Also as comment prevent using shadowed variable (res in map and in your function) so you can change it to

Before > `res['list'].map(res => res.main.temp_max)`

After > `res['list'].map(r => r.main.temp_max)`

And another improvement > `res.list.map(r => r.main.temp_max)`